# Disable Aero Shake mouse gesture but NOT keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I have long known about the "Aero Shake" group policy setting located in:

User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Desktop

But I have recently discovered that the policy name "Turn off Aero Shake window minimising mouse gesture" is quite misleading - it seems that it disables Aero Shake entirely, not just the mouse gesture (tested on W10 and W7).

I have a two part problem, where the first step is as follows: **I want to be able to use the Aero Shake keyboard shortcut, but still have the mouse gesture disabled.**

*...The second part of the problem is maybe there'd be some way to remap the shortcut from Win+Home to something less ridiculous which can be done by one hand, Ctrl+Caps or something, but for the sake of this SU post, I am only interested in the first part.*

I did browse various Aero Shake related posts on here before, seems like what I am trying to accomplish is quite uncommon.

If anyone has any suggestions which work, I would much appreciate it!

EDIT: User @Gantendo has helped me quite a lot. So the best way to proceed looks like this: to turn off Aero Shake in group policy, and re-create the functionality using a 3rd party scripting language. Minimising all inactive tabs seems to be the easy part (in terms of recreating), however bringing back minimised tabs, *the same tabs that were minimised*, is a little less obvious.

We tried an AutoHotKey script, however it had unintended consequences, and minimised away my start menu and taskbar - so @Gantendo has suggested using AutoIt scripting. We currently have a "WIP" code that should be able to minimise inactive tabs, and make a note of the tabs that are minimised along the way, so that the feature of "restoring tabs previously minimised by aero shake" can be implemented also.

Comment: @Gantendo Thanks for the comments, but to clarify: Aero Shake minimises all windows **apart from the active one**. Minimising active window is already possible thanks to Win + Down arrow. Sorry I didn't make it clearer, heh

Comment: Geez things are happening in real time, you wrote a comment whilst I was modifying mine - scared the crap out of me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, disable that option. Then create your own keyboard combo in, for example, AutoHotKey: https://pastebin.com/mrZxjSew

If you want to use a different key instead of F2 look at https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm

---

Another option is using AutoIt, which is pretty similar, here is a quick example:

https://pastebin.com/PHsU5sVj

Comment: Okay - I do have autohotkey, so am willing to give this a go. Do you happen to know if pressing again restores the previously open windows back to how they were? That is almost as important as the minimising part for me. Thanks

Comment: It currently doesn't, but you could easily add that functionality

Comment: Hmm, this is certainly a start. It's "slightly" worse than the built in one, because for example, if you have many things open, you can tell it's procedurally minimising each one, so it's not "instant", but that's not a problem! Now, as a user (not a coder!) of AHK scripts, I don't know how easy it would be for the script to make a note of each window it minimises, then reference that list to re-open the previously minimised stuff. But it is something I can spend time looking into. Thanks

Comment: I did encounter some strange graphical glitches in my taskbar when running two ahk scripts at the same time (before this, I had an AHK script that was always running in backgound, (some hotkeys to allow any window to be "always on top")). But I will keep using and monitor.

Comment: Well, I am personally more comfortable with AutoIt, and I found a nice little function you could use (before admins come to tell us this is not a scriptwriting service haha) I will update the answer above

Comment: @bfh47 see above, wrote a quick example

Comment: Hey! I also heard of AutoIt, someone found a way to make CMD seethrough glass using that, but I never installed it before. I am really very interested in trying AutoIt - bcause something funny has just happened. I was finding, what causes the taskbar glitchy pixels, and it seems that something bad might happen when I go to system tray after pressing the F2 shortcut, or maybe something bad happens when you press F2 with no windows open (desktop focused). I have managed to lose first my start menu, then my taskbar. And even restarting explorer doesn't fix it LOL. Hope it comes back after reboot!

Comment: @bfh47 Haha that is pretty cool. Yeah, a reboot will fix that; no worries. I highly recommend AutoIt, its like QBASIC if you are old enough to remember that. It is fun and easy to learn.

Comment: Phew, fixed. I am scared of that ahk script now... even though I set shortcut to "ctrl" + "caps lock", which was nice, the script obviously had some side effects haha. I will download AutoIt and give your script a try - I am guessing it just minimises the inactive tabs, right - nothing about bringing them back? Because that is fine, I can run such a script for now, until I can maybe code the other functionality also. Wow stackexchange doesn't like lots of commenting huh ;)

Comment: @bfh47 I like AHK but I prefer AutoIt the code is so much more readable! Yeah, currently it just minimises them, but I added some code I found online that makes a array of windows. This function/method can be used as a basis for an improved version. Yeah, the StackExchange interface leaves a lot to be desired. Props to AdamUL: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/193261-get-visible-windows/

Comment: @bfh47 If you can't figure it out, let me know; if I disappear ask my brothers and sisters and the rest at Stack Overflow. Decent chance they'll remove this question because it is technically offtopic so please copy paste everything to your PC (especially the pastebin link)

Comment: What? "a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users", we are certainly not off topic... but yes, a lot of comments, not what they like to see. Well, thanks. I will certainly do some testing and archive everything!